# Update Value in Vector

Tags: c++

```
   void Record::Update() {

string choice;

cout << "Enter ID: " << endl;
cin >> IDValue;
  for(Itr = List.begin() ; Itr !=List.end() ; Itr+) {
   if(Itr->GetID() == IDValue)
    { 
    cout << Transit->GetID() << endl;
    cout << "Would you like to set Name ?  (y/n) :";
    cin  >> choice;
    if ( choice == 'y' ) 
      cin >> strName;
    Itr->SetName(strName);

    cout << Itr->GetName() << endl;
    cout << Itr->GetLocation() << endl;
     }

   }
 }
```

This function finds a record by its unique ID number.  Each new record is given an ID number.  If I enter in ID 2 the function displays the record with ID 2.  How can I modify one of the attributes of the record?  In this case the location of it.

Comment: Who knows.  What type of object is stored in this container and does it allow you to modify the location?

Comment: Do you have mutator methods?  Will `Transit->SetID(9)` work?

Comment: I hate it when you create a new account everytime you ask questions:  * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860271  * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108853

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    void RecordList::UpdateLocation() {

    int IDValue;
    char* strName;
    char opt;

    cout << "Enter ID number to update: " << endl;
    cin >> IDValue;
      for(Transit = List.begin() ; Transit !=List.end() ; Transit++) {
       if(Transit->GetID() == IDValue)
        { 
        cout << Transit->GetID() << endl;
        cout << "Would you like to set Name ?  (y/n) :";
        cin  >> opt;
        if ( opt == 'y' ) 
          cin >> strName;
        Transit->SetName(strName);

        cout << Transit->GetName() << endl;
        cout << Transit->GetLocation() << endl;
        }

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was easier than I thought it would be.  I actually just created a new local variable and then entered it with Transit->SetName(strName);

Answer (score 0):

You program the Transit object to have a `setXXX()` method and then call that method.  Iterators work mostly like pointers so you can change a class variable with a setter method.